Is it possible to make the system bar overlap while not overlapping the navigation bar
fun setStatusBarTransparent() {
    window.apply {
        addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true)
    }
}

After doing the code above, both the status bar and the navigation bar become transparent and overlap with the ui.
I want to keep the status bar above and make sure that the navigation bar is not transparent and does not overlap with the ui.
What should I do?

That's wired, since you're recommended to implement edge-to-edge nowadays. 
Try this if it can help:
// Before setContentView in onCreate
enableEdgeToEdge(
    navigationBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.dark(Color.DARK)
)

// Then after setContentView
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(binding.root) { v, insets ->
    val inset = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
    // Make your root view padding the DARK navigationbar so that it will not cover your view content.
    v.updatePaddingRelative(
        bottom = inset.bottom
    )
    // Other insets handling...
    // Make your appbar fit system bars
    // Or set it via xml with fitSystemWindows=true

    insets
}


